# CakePhp pagination and my own function

Tags: cakephp

I have a big function in my model. It returns list of friends with their photos and profiles. There are two 'finds' with loops in body, so it is not easy.

Now I need to show this list with pagination.

Is threre any posibility to create pagination with my method?

There is no posibility to get this data in one find (or paginate) function.

Any ideas?

Comment: You haven't told us enough about your setup. Please edit your question and add your models and their relations *at the very least*. The more information you provide the better.

Comment: I just want to know if there is any posibility to create pagination with data returned by my own function.

Comment: Yes there is. http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/pagination.html#custom-query-pagination Didn't really warrant a SO question though if you only wanted to know *if*

Comment: I like the aproach this anwser, I implemented it and works fine: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6501849/paginate-from-within-a-model-in-cakephp#answer-6577042

Answer (score 2):

**Yes, it is possible.**

You can implement the `paginate()` and `paginateCount()` methods on your model, or include them in a behavior attached to your model. Behaviors implementing `paginate` and/or `paginateCount` should implement the method signatures defined below with the normal additional first parameter of `$model`:

[Custom Query Pagination](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/pagination.html#custom-query-pagination) will do the same stuff you needed.

Comment: This link might help you to achieve the same: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9636228/custom-pagination-in-cake-php

Comment: You can also make your own find method that will show the paginated data. Check this link: http://marianoiglesias.com.ar/cakephp/pagination-with-custom-find-types-in-cakephp/